# Is it possible to add parallax scrolling effect to other pages?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Normally parallax scrolling sites are only one page, and it scrolls to other pages. is there a way to scroll to other pages in the same site using JQuery and AJAX?? like from index.html to aboutus.html. Is it possible to do that? Or does Parallax scrolling only work on one page websites?

Thanks

Comment: You could build all of the website's information into one large parallax scrolling container. Or build a series of loads. There are many ways to attack this problem.

Comment: I hate it when sites try to come up with clever ways to transition between web pages. I don't WANT clever transitions. Transitions are for slideshows. When I leave one web page and load another, I want there to be no ambiguity whatsoever that I'm someplace different.